# I want to be able to isolate a non-specific string from a list using python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
```

I want to be able to remove the 'eth0' part from this string, but it may not always be eth0! Its positioning after the "2: " part is consistent though.

Any ideas?

edit:

The overall idea would be to isolate the interface name 'lo', 'eth0', etc.. Here's a longer example:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:c8:10:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.16/32 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.17/32 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.18/32 scope global eth0
3: gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: 3g-wan1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 3
    link/ppp
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's best to post code showing where your understanding is at, so people can orient their explanations towards it. I would suggest looking into re.sub().

Comment: `but it may not always be eth0!` What else may it be, then?

Comment: @Cthulhu it may be eth1, lo, eth0-0, wan1 ... depends on the specified interface name

Comment: @user2386137, what output exactly do you want for that longer example?

Comment: @Dogbert something along the lines of a list that contains 'l0', 'eth0', 'gre0' and '3g-wan1'

Comment: @user2386137, so an array of those strings?

Comment: @user2386137, check out my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: New answer for the updated question.

Use `re.findall(r'\d+: (.*?):', string)`

```
import re

string = """
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:c8:10:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.16/32 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.17/32 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.200.18/32 scope global eth0
3: gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: 3g-wan1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 3
    link/ppp
"""
print re.findall(r'\d+: (.*?):', string)
```

Output:

```
['lo', 'eth0', 'gre0', '3g-wan1']
```

Comment: @zmo, well the original question said `"2: " part is consistent though`. Will edit my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if the 2 is a fixed part. You can try variations around that:

```
import re
re.sub("(\d*:)[^:]*:(.*)", "\\1\\2", "2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000")
```

Result:

```
'2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000'
```

**EDIT:** It seems we all understood your expectations the wrong way. @Dogbert 's usage of `findall` would have my preference. However, I'll mention an adapted version of the `re.sub` proposal for closure. You could also do that by adapting the `re.sub` function call shown above:

```
>>> re.sub("\d*: *([^:]*):.*", "\\1", "2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000")
'eth0'
```

Comment: The 2 is not a fixed part. For example, I want to isolate lo, eth0, gre0 and 3g-wan1 in the updated example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for such simple manipulations.

Use `split()`. assuming `s` is your string:

```
pre, x, after = s.split(': ', 2)
s_without_x = ': '.join([pre, after])
```

results:

```
>>> x
'eth0'
>>> s_without_x
'2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000'
```

if you want to apply it to any line, you can check `if s[0].isdigit()`.

Answer (score 0):

On the output of that command there are two known things:

- the name of the interface we want to check
- the format `NB: NAME: DESCRIPTION`

so here's a regexp:

```
>>> s = "2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000"
>>> re.sub('\d+: eth0: ', '', s)
'<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000'
```

Now you can parameterize it:

```
>>> iface = 'eth0'
>>> s = "2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+: {}: '.format(iface), '', s)
'<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000'
```

so you can make it a function:

```
def get_iface_params(iface):
    out = subprocess.check_output(['ip', 'addr'])
    for s in out:
        if 'eth0' in s:
            return re.sub(r'\d+: {}: '.format(iface), '', s)
```

now if you call it with `iface` being `lo` as a parameter, it will give you the `lo` interface parameters.

HTH

Comment: The name of the interface is not always eth0.. I might try and find a way to get the specific interface names another way, and use this.

Comment: well that's why I suggest you use a parameter name `iface`